# How to change the name of the column after duplicate, and still keep the previous data at new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame with few columns. After i duplicate one of the columns ("Gamma"), i got two columns. now i want to change the name of the second "Gamma" to other name ("Vega"), and still keep the same data as before.

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4),
               index=pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=5),
               columns=['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'])

X1=(df.iloc[0:,2])
A1=pd.concat([df,X1], axis=1)
```

Both columns with same the name "Gamma" are changed to "Vega", and looks like this:

```
               Alpha      Beta      Vega     Delta      Vega
2012-01-01  1.183407  1.621138 -0.265026  1.281414 -0.265026
2012-01-02  0.242500  1.447831  1.416176  0.213390  1.416176
2012-01-03  2.561872  0.772370  0.491330  0.441862  0.491330
2012-01-04 -0.520791  0.295666 -0.426005 -0.302739 -0.426005
2012-01-05 -0.076098 -0.118959  0.252242 -0.995290  0.252242
```

So, how can i select the correct "Gamma" column (the second one), and how to change his name only.

My expected output is:

```
               Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta      Vega
2012-01-01  1.183407  1.621138 -0.265026  1.281414 -0.265026
2012-01-02  0.242500  1.447831  1.416176  0.213390  1.416176
2012-01-03  2.561872  0.772370  0.491330  0.441862  0.491330
2012-01-04 -0.520791  0.295666 -0.426005 -0.302739 -0.426005
2012-01-05 -0.076098 -0.118959  0.252242 -0.995290  0.252242
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple `assign` will do it.

```
A1 = df.assign(Vega=df['Gamma'])
print (A1)
               Alpha      Beta     Gamma     Delta      Vega
2012-01-01 -2.695081 -1.934733  0.892127 -0.895014  0.892127
2012-01-02 -0.911289  0.714030  0.531698  1.435397  0.531698
2012-01-03 -1.374162  1.517784  0.321945  1.268438  0.321945
2012-01-04 -0.103294 -0.483923 -0.661366 -0.829013 -0.661366
2012-01-05 -2.700309  0.601139  1.940421 -0.489158  1.940421
```

Comment: your solution looks like good, but: In DataFrame i see : Alpha, Beta, Vega, Delta and Gamma. i want to see: Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta and Vega. Also, where in your code i can recognize the specific column, that you selected?

Comment: Thanks! short and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Basic pandas if I understand you correctly.

```
df["Vega"] = df["Gamma"]
```

Comment: This isn't what OP asked for. The idea is not to create a new column, but to rename an existing one.

Comment: Are you sure? Why not?

Comment: Sorry mate, you're talking rubbish. The OP clearly just wants the output they specified, they don't care about the intermediate step of creating an identical column with the same name. Why would anyone require that?

Comment: Fair enough, but they are trying to create a new DataFrame while yours modifies the original, so this is still not what OP wants. My downvote will remain for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concating and re-naming the column, you directly add the column with desired column name and desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4),
           index=pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=5),
           columns=['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta'])

df["Vega"]=(df.iloc[0:,2])
```